# Release eclipse plugin that bundles Linux binary

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I created a plugin for eclipse that calls a binary file using the processBuilder.
This all works great but when I package the plugin as a Jar the file permissions are gone and I cannot run it.

I read something that I should package the binary in a feature so can make it a root file and set permissions. Now I am unclear how to call this root file (what is the location).

How should I be doing this? after a few days of trying I am getting a bit desperate :S.

Basically, I want to create a plugin that calls a binary and uses the output in a view.

Comment: Just searching the Eclipse help for 'rootfile' gives quite a lot of information about this. Have you read it?

Comment: Yes I did read it. In the meantime I have my binary in the root of my feature folder.
But is this the way to go and how do I call it from my plugin.

Comment: The directives in the feature copy the file to a specific location in the Eclipse installation when the feature is installed and set the permissions if you use 'root.permissions'. You just specify the correct location in your ProcessBuilder call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a feature you can configure files to be copied in to the installation using the `root` and `root.permissions` directives in the `build.properties` file.

At the simplest this might just be:

```
root=file:myExecutable
root.permissions.755=myExecutable
```

Which will copy a `myExecutable` file from the feature folder to the installation root and set its permissions to `755`.

In your plug-in you can use `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` to find out the install root location:

```java
URL rootURL = Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL();
```

Comment: Thanks greg.
Got to this answer with the earlier comment you gave.
Much appreciated!